# Process output data from YOLOv5 TFlite

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow-lite, yolov5

### ❔Question

Hi, I have successfully trained a custom model based on YOLOv5s and converted the model to TFlite. I feel silly asking, but how do you use the output data?

I get as output:

- StatefulPartitionedCall: 0 = [1,25200,7]
  from the converted YOLOv5 model
  [Netron YOLOv5s.tflite model](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/58934176/105021013-554a2600-5a48-11eb-90ef-6656a7fe63bb.png)

But I expect an output like:

- StatefulPartitionedCall:3 = [1, 10, 4] # boxes
- StatefulPartitionedCall:2 = [1, 10] # classes
- StatefulPartitionedCall:1 = [1, 10] #scores
- StatefulPartitionedCall:0 = [1] #count
  (this one is from a tensorflow lite mobilenet model (trained to give 10 output data, default for tflite))
  [Netron mobilenet.tflite model](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/58934176/105020926-3d72a200-5a48-11eb-8f48-406ae1524d24.png)

It may also be some other form of output, but I honestly have no idea how to get the boxes, classes, scores from a [1,25200,7] array.
(on 15-January-2021 I updated pytorch, tensorflow and yolov5 to the latest version)

The data contained in the [1, 25200, 7] array can be found in this file: [outputdata.txt](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/files/5848088/outputdata.float.txt)

```
0.011428807862102985, 0.006756599526852369, 0.04274776205420494, 0.034441519528627396, 0.00012877583503723145, 0.33658933639526367, 0.4722323715686798
0.023071227595210075, 0.006947836373001337, 0.046426184475421906, 0.023744791746139526, 0.0002465546131134033, 0.29862138628959656, 0.4498370885848999
0.03636947274208069, 0.006819264497607946, 0.04913407564163208, 0.025004519149661064, 0.00013208389282226562, 0.3155967593193054, 0.4081345796585083
0.04930267855525017, 0.007249316666275263, 0.04969717934727669, 0.023645592853426933, 0.0001222355494974181, 0.3123127520084381, 0.40113094449043274
...
```

Should I add a Non Max Suppression or something else, can someone help me please? ([github YOLOv5 #1981](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/1981))

Comment: Apparently there is an error to the procedure of creating the model...or converting to tflite. You should see 3-4 outputs at Netron and not just 1. Check again...the creation of the model

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to @Glenn Jocher I found the solution. The output is `[xywh, conf, class0, class1, ...]`

My current code is now:

```
def classFilter(classdata):
    classes = []  # create a list
    for i in range(classdata.shape[0]):         # loop through all predictions
        classes.append(classdata[i].argmax())   # get the best classification location
    return classes  # return classes (int)

def YOLOdetect(output_data):  # input = interpreter, output is boxes(xyxy), classes, scores
    output_data = output_data[0]                # x(1, 25200, 7) to x(25200, 7)
    boxes = np.squeeze(output_data[..., :4])    # boxes  [25200, 4]
    scores = np.squeeze( output_data[..., 4:5]) # confidences  [25200, 1]
    classes = classFilter(output_data[..., 5:]) # get classes
    # Convert nx4 boxes from [x, y, w, h] to [x1, y1, x2, y2] where xy1=top-left, xy2=bottom-right
    x, y, w, h = boxes[..., 0], boxes[..., 1], boxes[..., 2], boxes[..., 3] #xywh
    xyxy = [x - w / 2, y - h / 2, x + w / 2, y + h / 2]  # xywh to xyxy   [4, 25200]

    return xyxy, classes, scores  # output is boxes(x,y,x,y), classes(int), scores(float) [predictions length]
```

To get the output data:

```
"""Output data"""
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])  # get tensor  x(1, 25200, 7)
xyxy, classes, scores = YOLOdetect(output_data) #boxes(x,y,x,y), classes(int), scores(float) [25200]
```

And for the boxes:

```
for i in range(len(scores)):
    if ((scores[i] > 0.1) and (scores[i] <= 1.0)):
        H = frame.shape[0]
        W = frame.shape[1]
        xmin = int(max(1,(xyxy[0][i] * W)))
        ymin = int(max(1,(xyxy[1][i] * H)))
        xmax = int(min(H,(xyxy[2][i] * W)))
        ymax = int(min(W,(xyxy[3][i] * H)))

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin,ymin), (xmax,ymax), (10, 255, 0), 2)
        ...
```

Comment: Hi @Tommydw. Thanks for this post. It helps me a lot. Nonetheless, I am trying to inference on a android device, so the result data comes from android platform, which does not uses python, and use Kotlin or Java. I'm actually having a hard time trying to implement this on Java or Kotlin, as I'm not so familiar on Android platform. I'm curious if this code can change the model itself, or did you just use this on Python platform? Thanks!

Comment: @JinmoChong did you find a way to implement the above in android